# How to make a mesh draggable only in x & y direction according to camera?

Tags: draggable, mesh, babylonjs

I want my child meshes to be draggable only in x & y direction with respect to the camera. I am using free camera of Babylon. Tried using the "Left Right Dragger" and "DragPlaneNormal" but could not achieve the desired result, the mesh is draggable in z direction.

```
const axis = new BABYLON.Vector3(0,1,0);

const leftRightDragger = new BABYLON.PointerDragBehavior({dragAxis: axis});
leftRightDragger.moveAttached = true;
clone_child[child].addBehavior(leftRightDragger);

or

var pointerDragBehavior = new BABYLON.PointerDragBehavior({dragPlaneNormal: new BABYLON.Vector3(1,1,0)});
clone_child[child].addBehavior(pointerDragBehavior);
pointerDragBehavior.useObjectOrientationForDragging = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

use babylonjs life cycle method.

```js
const mesh // the mesh now dragging
const zPos = mesh.position.z

scene.registerBeforeRender(() => {
  mesh.position.z = zPos
})
```